# How to change my onboard keyboard theme in lightdm gtk+

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, lightdm, onboard

I'm running Xubuntu 14.04.02 and have created a custom Onboard keyboard theme, which works fine once I'm logged in.  The problem is my greeter screen, when I launch Onboard it keeps the default theme of "Nightshade".  Is there a way to change the theme onboard uses via lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf or another way to use my custom theme?

Answer (score 0):

Add "--theme=ThemeName" argument to onboard command in lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf:

```
[greeter]
keyboard=onboard --theme=HighContrast
```